# How to quick search in huge range-value pairs?

Tags: algorithm, search, range

For example we have some range-value pairs:

```
<<1, 2>, 65>
<<3, 37>, 75>
<<45, 159>, 12>
<<160, 200>, 23>
<<210, 255>, 121>
```

And these ranges are disjoint.

Give a integer `78`, and the corresponding range is `<45, 159>`, so output the value `12`.

As the range maybe very large, I now use `map` to storage these range-value pairs.
Evevy searching will scan the entire map set, it's `O(n)`.

Is there any good ways except **binary search**?

Comment: Binary search is actually fine. You can find the range in O(log n). (Be sure to sort your ranges by the first component). (So to clarify: If you don't mind O(n) insertion, then don't use a map, but a plain array which is very cache friendly)

Comment: "Evevy searching will scan the entire map set, it's O(n).". You're doing something wrong.

Comment: Every searching shouldn't scan the entire map

Comment: If the set of ranges is dynamic you could use a (range) tree, which also has O(log N) complexity.

Comment: Are  you using C++? Sounds like it, because you are using `map`. Confirm?

Answer (score 2):

Binary search is definitely your best option. O(log n) is hard to beat!

If you don't want to hand-code the binary search, and you're using C++, you can use the `std::map::upper_bound` function, which implements binary search:

```
std::map<std::pair<int, int>, int> my_map;
int val = 78; // value to search for
auto it = my_map.upper_bound(std::make_pair(val, val));
if(it != my_map.begin()) it--;
if(it->first.first <= val && it->first.second >= val) {
    /* Found it, value is it->second */
} else {
    /* Didn't find it */
}
```

`std::map::upper_bound` is guaranteed to run in logarithmic time, because the `map` is inherently sorted (and usually implemented as a red-black tree). It returns the element after the element you're searching for, and hence the iterator that it returns is decremented to obtain a useful iterator.

Comment: won't you get a seg fault if the map is empty or you hit the first element?  :-) or if what you are looking for is not in the map?

Comment: @AK_: Yes, I'm assuming the map is non-empty. This should hopefully be obvious. It won't fail if the element isn't in the map, because the `it--` makes the iterator always point to a valid element (if the map is nonempty).

Answer (score 0):

How about a [Binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree)?

Though you'll probably need a self balancing search tree: [AVL Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) and [Red black trees are a good start](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree), but you probably should stick with something that you already have in your "Ecosystem" for .Net that would be a [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx),probably with a costum [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but that's just an example...

---

For C++ you should use an ordered map, with a custom compare [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)

Links:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

---

Again for C++, I would do something like (without compiler, so careful) :

```
class Comparer 
{
    bool operator()(pair<int,int> const & one, pair<int,int> const & two) 
    {
        if (a.second < b.first) 
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
        return false;
        }
     }
};
```

then you define the map as:

```
map<pair<int,int>,int,Comparer> myMap;

myMap.insert(make_pair(make_pair(-3,9),1));

int num = myMap[make_pair(7,7)]
```